# How to change href attribute using JavaScript after opening the link in a new window?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link on my page

```
<a href="http://google.com" id="mylink" onclick="changeLink();" target="_blank">google</a>
```

And the goal is to follow this link (opening in a new tab) and change its attributes (on previous tab). I mean we open google.com in a new tab and if we look back on the link, it's refreshed.

I've tried this js code

```
function changeLink(){
    document.getElementById("mylink").href = "http://facebook.com";
    document.getElementById("mylink").innerHTML = "facebook";
    }
```

But it also changes the target of new opening tab. Instead of opening google it opens facebook in my example.

Is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Your `onclick` fires before the href so it will change before the page is opened, you need to make the function handle the window opening like so:

```
function changeLink() {
    var link = document.getElementById("mylink");

    window.open(
      link.href,
      '_blank'
    );

    link.innerHTML = "facebook";
    link.setAttribute('href', "http://facebook.com");

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can delay your code using `setTimeout` to execute after click

```
function changeLink(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        var link = document.getElementById("mylink");
        link.setAttribute('href', "http://facebook.com");
        document.getElementById("mylink").innerHTML = "facebook";
    }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
onclick="changeLink();"
```

by

```
onclick="changeLink(); return false;"
```

to cancel its default action

Answer (score 0):

You can change this in the page `load`.

My intention is that when the page comes to the `load` function, switch the links (the current link in the required one)

Answer (score 0):

for example try this:

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="myLink1">open link 1</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com" id="myLink2">open link 2</a>
```

```js
document.getElementById("myLink1").onclick = function() {
    window.open("http://www.facebook.com");
    return false;
};
    
document.getElementById("myLink2").onclick = function() {
    window.open("http://www.yahoo.com");
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in my own Case it was a react code i used a map method on my nav links and the href attibute simply takes you to to the place in the page.

```
<ul className="app__navbar-links">{[
              "About",
              "Impact report",
              "Our programs",
              "Resources",
              "Blog",
              "Free downloads",
              "Join community",
            ].map((item, index) => (
              <li className="app__flex" key={index}>
                <div />

                <a href={`#${item}`} id="nav-link" onClick={handleBlogClick}>
                  {" "}
                  {item}
                </a>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
```

i needed a new tab only on the blog nav. The set Attribute opens a new tab but it doesnt default to the new tabs origin and it refreshes the whole page. But this solution worked for me.

```
const handleBlogClick = (event) => {
    const navLink = document.querySelectorAll("#nav-link");
    if (event.target === navLink[4]) {
      const blogNav = navLink[4];
      console.log(blogNav);
      console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
      window.open(
        "https://www.linkedin.com/company/ideas-worth-billions/",
        "_blank",
        "noopener,noreferrer"
      );

      blogNav.innerHTML = "Blog";
      return false;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

Is there any downside of leveraging `mousedown` listener to modify the `href` attribute with a new URL location and then let the browser figures out where it should redirect to?

It's working fine so far for me. Would like to know what the limitations are with this approach?

```
// Simple code snippet to demonstrate the said approach
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.textContent = 'test link';
a.href = '/haha';
a.target = '_blank';
a.rel = 'noopener';

a.onmousedown = () => {
  a.href = '/lol';
};

document.body.appendChild(a);
}
```