# How to dynamically add a link to a button?

Tags: javascript

This is tied to this question.

[How can I dynamically add an HREF as a field is filled out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62307480/how-can-i-dynamically-add-an-href-as-a-field-is-filled-out?noredirect=1#comment110197276_62307480)

I had success getting the link to work but it has been decided that the link would be better as a button. Here is what I have for the link.

The function I used

```
function buildPMLink(){
       let urlStart = "https://www.projectmanagement.com?query=";
       let urlEnd = "&showResults=False";
       let campRef = document.getElementByID("campid").value;
       let fullURL = urlStart + campRef + urlEnd;
       document.getElementById('pmURL').href = fullURL;

    }
```

The field that triggers the function

```
<div class="input-field col s3">
    <input placeholder="Enter Campaign ID" id="campid" type="text" class="validate" oninput="buildWFLink(); buildPMLink();" required >
    <label for="campaign_id">Campaign ID</label>
</div>
```

The link I added the dynamic HREF to.

```
<div >
     <a id="pmURL">Test</a>
 </div>
```

I tried creating a button and wrapping that in a form hoping to use the form action but failed. What am I missing?

Comment: Just edit the href to style as a button if you want a quick and dirty solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something very simple like this:

```
<a id="pmURL"><button>Test</button></a>
```

Comment: Get out of here! I could have sworn I tried that and failed. Works great!