# Change HTML attributes dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

Can somebody explain where I'm making mistake, please..!

Create a link that says “Buy Tickets” and has a href attribute of “tickets.html”.

Create a button that says “Upgrade”.

When the user clicks “Upgrade”, the “Buy Tickets” link url should change from “tickets.html” to “fancy_tickets.html”.

```
<script>
document.getElementById("upgrade").onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById("buylink").href = "fancy_tickets.html";
};
</script>

<html>
<body>
<a id="buylink" href="tickets.html">Buy Tickets</a><br>
  <button id ="upgrade">Upgrade</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like you are learning JavaScript. https://www.w3schools.com/js/ is a great place to learn.

Comment: Thank you Oliver yes Im learning JS so many questions and need answers for me to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have a typo in closing `<script>`, missing `/`, should be `</script>`. Then your script is running before the DOM is fully loaded. You can either place the script at the bottom of the *body* tag or wrap your code with [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event:

```html
<script>

  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    document.getElementById("upgrade").onclick = function () {
      var el = document.getElementById("buylink");
      el.href = "fancy_tickets.html";
      console.log(el.getAttribute('href'));// log the new href value
    };
  });

</script>

<a id="buylink" href="ticket.html">Buy Tickets</a><br>
<button id="upgrade">Upgrade</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like it says in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385207/how-to-change-href-attribute-using-javascript-after-opening-the-link-in-a-new-wi), you should use the `setAttribute(atr, value);` method, something like `document.getElementById("buylink").setAttribute("href", "fancy_tickets.html");`. Also i suggest you to use addEventListener to listen to events such as onClick

```
const upgradeBtn = document.getElementById("upgrade");
const buyLink = document.getElementById("buylink");

upgradeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
   buyLink.setAttribute("href", "fancy_tickets.html");
});
```

Comment: Hi Fliotta thanks for answering, i understand manipulating that href="tickets.html" attribute, with this code document.getElementById("buylink").href = "fancy_tickets.html";
**This is the part I don't understand..! Create a button that says “Upgrade”.

When the user clicks “Upgrade”, the “Buy Tickets” link url should change from “tickets.html” to “fancy_tickets.html”.**

Comment: I tried it after clicking the button it is not taking me to the link fancy_tickets.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well. You forgot to specify the `id="upgrade"` attribute for the `button` tag.

```js
document.getElementById("upgrade").onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById("buylink").href = "fancy_tickets.html";
};
```

```html
<a id="buylink" href="tickets.html">Buy Tickets</a><br>
  <button id="upgrade">Upgrade</button>
```

Comment: I tried that the button is not taking me to the link fancy_tickets.html

Comment: it works now thank you I have to add target ='_blank' to see that

Comment: glad to help.. did you need to switch to a new browser tab?

Comment: its so weird  this is the only way after clciking the button its taking me to fancy_tickets.html page **<a id="buylink" href="ticket.html" target="_blank" Buy Tickets</a><br>
  <button id="upgrade">Upgrade</button>** document.getElementById("upgrade").onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById("buylink").href = "fancy_tickets.html";
}; **but i cant see the buytickets page because target="_blank" Buy Tickets</a> ** if i close the target attribute the button is not working

Comment: This is not the only way to go to the page. If I understood you correctly, then - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript

Comment: Always glad to help

Answer (score 0):

```js
function switch1()
{  document.getElementById("buylink").href = "fancy_tickets.html";
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<a target=_blank id="buylink" href="tickets.html">Buy Tickets</a><br>
  <button id="upgrade" onclick="javascript:switch1();">Upgrade</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried it after clicking the button it is not taking me to the link fancy_tickets.html